# How to explain a summary page in R

Tags: r

Does anyone know how to explain all my code- which is a summary file/ page from R?

Thanks!

```
Call:
lm(formula = `Home Run Factor` ~ `Average Outfield Dimension`, 
    data = Capstone_Baseball)

Residuals:
     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
-0.31584 -0.09443 -0.01813  0.11085  0.27891 

Coefficients:
                              Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)
(Intercept)                  -1.068759   1.531011  -0.698    0.491
`Average Outfield Dimension`  0.005738   0.004224   1.358    0.185

Residual standard error: 0.1525 on 28 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.06183,   Adjusted R-squared:  0.02832 
F-statistic: 1.845 on 1 and 28 DF,  p-value: 0.1852
```

Comment: Are you asking how to interpret the statistical meaning and power of the parts of this output *in general*? Or are you asking us to determine statistical significance of these fields in your data in this specific model?

Comment: While you can get an answer on SO, I think the answer to both possibles are better suited for [CrossValidated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/). (My opinion on the model: not the biggest sample, not the strongest p-value (which is not enough anyway), and the R-squared is rather low ... I'd say this is telling you to include more dependent variables and/or transforms.)

Comment: I just want to know the statistical meaning of the data, specifically the statistics under coefficients and the p-value. Thank you so much!

Comment: Is this for a class? The teacher or TAs should be answering that question for you before having you dive into output from these models. Is this for an online tutorial? Perhaps read another subchapter or chapter, as I would imagine definitions/explanations would be forthcoming. Please forgive the direct (crass) method of this comment, but SO is not the place to dive into the statistical inferences to be taken from this output.

Comment: I see, sorry.  This is for a class.  I just need basic information, but it's ok.  Do you perhaps know what the estimate means for the 'average outfield dimension- the x-axis of my graph'?

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/59250/60634